# SWIFT - detect webview full screen vdeo ENTER and EXIT and Handle that

Tags: swift, webview, io, uiwebview

i want to detect video fullscreen enter and exit in a webview and do some code in each case , what are the events i need to catch and handle , does the observer do the trick , it is vital for me to show certain options to the user and modify the interface.

here a part of my code i useed for the webview

please help save my day

```
 func loadWebSite() {
    let theConfiguration:WKWebViewConfiguration? = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let thisPref:WKPreferences = WKPreferences()
    thisPref.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
    thisPref.javaScriptEnabled = true
    theConfiguration!.preferences = thisPref;

    self.wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: self.getFrame(), configuration: theConfiguration!)


    self.wkWebView?.navigationDelegate = self
    self.wkWebView?.uiDelegate = self
    self.wkWebView?.bridge.printScriptMessageAutomatically = true
    self.wkWebView?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loading", options: .new, context: nil)
    self.wkWebView?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "estimatedProgress", options: .new, context: nil)
    self.wkWebView?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "VideoExitFullScreen", options: .new, context: nil)
    self.wkWebView?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "VideoEnterFullScreen", options: .new, context: nil)


}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if (keyPath == "loading") {
        self.backButton?.isEnabled = self.wkWebView!.canGoBack
        self.forwardButton?.isEnabled = self.wkWebView!.canGoForward
    } else if (keyPath == "estimatedProgress") {
        let estimatedProgress = Float(self.wkWebView!.estimatedProgress)
        if estimatedProgress > 0.90 {

        }
    }else if (keyPath == "VideoExitFullScreen") {
        // DO CODE HERE
    } else if (keyPath == "VideoEnterFullScreen") {
        // DO CODE HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: Same question here. Is there any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

What I wanted was to detect when a video exited full screen and play it again.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onDidEnterFullscreen(_:)), name: UIWindow.didBecomeVisibleNotification, object: webview)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onDidLeaveFullscreen(_:)), name: UIWindow.didBecomeHiddenNotification, object: webview)

@objc func onDidEnterFullscreen(_ notification: Notification) {
      print("video is now playing in fullscreen")
}

@objc func onDidLeaveFullscreen(_ notification: Notification) {
      print("video has stopped playing in fullscreen")
      
      // This line plays the video again when exiting full screen
      webview?.evaluateJavaScript("var videos = document.getElementsByTagName(\"video\");  for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) { videos.item(i).play(); };")
}
```